Не сохраняется значение счетчика Kotlin Decompose
Разбираю библиотеку Decompose Аркадия Иванова по итогу при изменении счетчика и смены экрана, счетчик не сохраняет свое значение и обнуляется.
Интерфейс компонента
interface SecondComponent {
    val model: Value<Model>

    fun onIncrementClicked()
    fun onDecrementClicked()
    fun onBackClicked()

    data class Model(
       val count: Int = 0
    )
}

Реализация интерфейса
class DefaultSecondComponent(
    private val componentContext: ComponentContext,
    private val onBack: () -> Unit,
): SecondComponent, ComponentContext by componentContext{
     private val state = MutableValue(Model())
     override val model: Value<Model> = state

     override fun onIncrementClicked() {
         state.update { it.copy(count = it.count + 1)}
     }

     override fun onDecrementClicked() {
        state.update { it.copy(count = it.count - 1) }
     }

     override fun onBackClicked() {
        onBack()
     }
}

Создание навигации с помощью ChildStack
private fun secondComponent(component: ComponentContext): 
    SecondComponent =
         DefaultSecondComponent(
            componentContext = component,
            onBack = navigation::pop
         )

